# How to Sumif a Sum

Tags: postgresql, sum

I am trying to get a "total override" but only sum if the agent = x,y or z

```
SELECT   
    DISTINCT( "public"."rdf_dean"."agent_name" )  AS "Agent",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.9) AS "Paid to Agent",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.1) AS "Overrides",
    SUM overrides IF agent_name = x OR agent_name = y OR agent_name = z

FROM     "public"."rdf_dean"
WHERE "public"."rdf_dean"."created_date" = date(now())
GROUP BY agent_name
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. `distinct (a), b, c` is the same as `distinct a, b, c` or `distinct a, b, (c)`

Comment: Thank you, I just copied and pasted and didn't take the parenthesis out, being lazy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to have both aggregates for all rows and for some you can use FILTER (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html):

```
SELECT   
    "public"."rdf_dean"."agent_name" AS "Agent",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.9) AS "Paid to Agent",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.1) AS "Overrides",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.1) 
        FILTER (WHERE agent_name = x OR agent_name = y OR agent_name = z)
        AS "Partial Overrides",
FROM     "public"."rdf_dean"
WHERE "public"."rdf_dean"."created_date" = date(now())
GROUP BY agent_name
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your request you need to sum up on totals only in case agent is x, y, z

So either nested query:

```
SELECT "Agent", sum("Overrides")
FROM 
(
SELECT   
    "public"."rdf_dean"."agent_name"   AS "Agent",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.9) AS "Paid to Agent",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.1) AS "Overrides"
FROM     "public"."rdf_dean"
WHERE "public"."rdf_dean"."created_date" = date(now())
GROUP BY agent_name
) as data 
WHERE 
data."Agent" in (x, y, z)
```

Or

```
SELECT   
    "public"."rdf_dean"."agent_name"   AS "Agent",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.9) AS "Paid to Agent",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.1) AS "Overrides"
FROM     "public"."rdf_dean"
WHERE "public"."rdf_dean"."created_date" = date(now())
AND  "public".rdf_dean.agent_name in (x, y, z) 
GROUP BY agent_name
```

Or if you need to have both,  Paid to Agent and overrides only by agents

```
SELECT   
    "public"."rdf_dean"."agent_name"   AS "Agent",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.9) AS "Paid to Agent",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.1) AS "Overrides", 
    (SELECT SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.1) 
      FROM  "public"."rdf_dean"  internal 
      WHERE 
         internal.agent_name = out.agent_name 
         AND 
         internal.agent_name in (x, y, z)  ) AS "OverridesXYZ"
FROM     "public"."rdf_dean" out
WHERE "public"."rdf_dean"."created_date" = date(now())
GROUP BY agent_name
```

Or you can

```
SELECT   
    "public"."rdf_dean"."agent_name"   AS "Agent",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.9) AS "Paid to Agent",
    SUM("public"."rdf_dean"."paidcomm" *.1) AS "Overrides", 
    SUM(internal.paidcomm * .1)  AS "OverridesXYZ"
FROM     "public"."rdf_dean" out
LEFT JOIN public.rdf_dean internal ON internal.agent_name = out.agent_name  AND internal.agent_name in (x, y, z)   
WHERE "public"."rdf_dean"."created_date" = date(now())
GROUP BY agent_name
```

Comment: The 2nd Query worked, however I think I need to explain better what I want.  I only need the Override to calculate for the specific agents "x, y,z" however I still need the "Paid to Agent" sums to show up for all the other agents, a,b,c etc...